# scala list of anonymous functions

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Like to create a list of function literals and (a) avoid pre-defining them and (b) use shorthand syntax. Failing at the moment.

```
def g = (x: Int) => x + 1 //pre-defined

def h = (x: Int) => x + 2

List(g,h) //succeeds

List( (x: Int) => x + 1, (x: Int) => x + 2) ) //fails
      ^';' expected but ')' found.
```

Comment: The last one fails because you have an extra closing parenthesis. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify, do you know types of your functions in advance?

If yes, then you can explicitly specify type of your list:

```
@ List[Int=>Int](x => x + 1, x => x + 2)

res20: List[Int => Int] = List(<function1>, <function1>)
```

Or even shorter:

```
@ List[Int=>Int](_ + 1, _ + 2)

res21: List[Int => Int] = List(<function1>, <function1>)
```

If you want List type to be inferred, try following syntax:

```
@ List({ x: Int => x + 1}, { x: Int => x + 2 })
res22: List[Int => Int] = List(<function1>, <function1>)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was info I needed.

Comment: Hi, I know only return type, function signature are different. What is the right syntax to define it? Here is my function: ```def call(callMe: => Future[MyResponse]):Future[MyResponse] ={
    callMe
  }``` What is the right to pass list of such functions?

Comment: @Sergey, I think you should create separate question and describe your case in details.